# How to hide default services endpoint in Abp

Tags: abp

I want to hide default services endpoint in Abp Example bellow

AbpTenant

AbpServiceProxyScript

AbpApplicationConfigurationScript

AbpApplicationConfiguration
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXS90.png)

Comment: Please consider to add some code or screenshot

Comment: see the this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXS90.png

Answer (score 1):

You can use DocInclusionPredicate() in context.Services.AddSwaggerGen() to filter the api that you want to include or exclude. In the example below, only api with specific path will be included.

```cs
private static void ConfigureSwaggerServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
{
    context.Services.AddSwaggerGen(
        options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
                options.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, description) =>
            {
                // Generate only api that related to my api
                return description.RelativePath.IndexOf("specify path to your api here") >= 0;
            });
        });
}
```

See https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#customize-the-action-selection-process for more details